# I Cannot see some JSON objects in postman that i can see in firefox network analyzer tool

Tags: json, api, web-scraping, python-requests, postman

I have made a request for a URL and checked in a firefox network tool which is in devtools of firefox browser, I have a set of variables in it but when I made a request through postman client. I can see only limited set of keys and move over, I got same response as postman from a python Library called Requests library.

actually, what I'm messing in postman output is necessary to me. I have to work with that only.

**This is the output what I see in browser network tool :**

```
jsonp: true
success: 1
localPips:
localFacilities:
localCamps:
isNest: true
► localMarkers: Object ( 6: {...}, 60: {...}, 242: {...}, ... }
t_level: 0
```

and here we can expand **localMarkers** where the required data is.
*since it is a long response i am not sending it here! But if you need it i can try to send it or i will choose an alternate to bring that JSON response into your notice..*

**Now This is the bock what i see in the postman client :**

```
{
    "_jsonp": true,
    "success":1,
    "t_level":0
}
```

here in postman and python i can see only these three.

***if we are not able to get this response in postman is there any other way to get this data?***

**Below I'm attaching detailed screen shots :**

[This image is from firefox tool you can find the blue highlighted data that is what I expect from the url response.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOQnl.png)

[This is the output of same url. but the key named **localMarkers** is missing. same output from python request library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmebv.png)

Comment: Read about [mcve] and think how you can improve your question so readers can duplicate your problem in their local environments. LInks to screen shots are not ideal. If possible use copy/paste using the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on the select text so formatting is like `code/data/errMsgs`. Then expert readers can search in their browser for key words, etc. in what you have posted. Good luck.